# Blazor WASM Sophos [Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource] ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: windows, ssl, blazor, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022

I've had the "Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource" error show up in my console logs from time to time in published files, but never locally. Out of the blue this started happening to me a couple days ago, and I've spent the last two days trying to fix it. I am also getting the error about my self-signed certificates being invalid. Here are the things I've tried.

- Rebuild/Clean solution
- Delete all bin/obj folders
- Usually use chrome, but tried Firefox/Edge
- Attempted to run via CLI `dotnet watch` this actually strangely worked in some scenarios but has since stopped working.
- Uninstalled/Reinstalled IIS Express
- Uninstalled/Reinstalled VS 2022
- Ran `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` and `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` multiple times to recreate localhost certificates, but I still am getting the ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error.
- Confirmed that the localhost certificate is present in both the `Current User/Personal` and `Current User/Trusted Root Certification Authorities` folder.
- Closed visual studio deleted bin/obj/ .vs rebooted computer and tried again.
- A rain dance around an open fire

It seems like there has to be some simple solution involving certificates, but I've tried everything I can think of, as an additional note my work PC is running SOPHOS, I have seen that it has blocked some DLLs, but its blocking is sporadic, so I am not convinced this is the source of the problem. Additional details:

- VS2022 17.4.4
- .NET 7
- Blazor WASM Hosted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I didn't think it was my firewall....it was my firewall. Sophos was blocking the Blazor WASM dlls as mentioned in this issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21996

The telltale sign is in the response to the blocked dlls.

[image: Network tab showing blocked requests]

The resolution in my case was to contact our IT department and have them create  a firewall exception for my computer.

Comment: Any other way to resolve this? Our IT department doesn't want to create an exception.

Comment: Not that I could find at the time, unless that aspnetcore issue has been updated.